# Radio button check/uncheck works in all browsers, except for Opera v12x

Tags: jquery, radio-button, opera

We need to allow users to uncheck radio buttons (no, we can't use checkboxes instead).

Following jQuery code works just fine in all major browsers and versions, except for Opera:

```
$('body').on('click change', 'input:radio', function () {
    $(this).prop('checked') ? $(this).prop('checked',false) : $(this).prop('checked',true);
});
```

It seems as if Opera is choking on the 'click change' selector. Any ideas?

You can [try it](http://jsfiddle.net/aQ2UQ/2/) yourself.

**What happens:**
In Opera, when clicking on the radio button, "nothing happens". It is not possible to check the button. In slow motion (debug mode), though, one can see that it checks and then unchecks the radio button.

**Update:**
According to feedback, it seems to work in Opera v21x. It is however not working in v12x. Not sure about other versions.

Comment: Why you don't use checkbox instead?

Comment: ^ if this was a joke, it was awesome. lol

Comment: Works fine here in Opera.

Comment: @j08691 Not working here on Windows 7, Opera 12.16. What OS + Browser Version do you use?

Comment: @j08691 Opera 21?! I've just upgraded to the latest version: 12.17, Build 1863

Comment: http://www.opera.com/docs/changelogs/windows/

Comment: @j08691 Ok, right. In version 12x, however, it's still not working, and our analytics show that of all our Opera visitors, ~40% are using 12x. Thus, still looking for help. Thx!

Comment: I don't have a way to test Opera 12 at the moment, but you might want to try this small change in your code and see if it works in Opera 12: http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/j825r/

Comment: @j08691 Still not working :-/

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

`$("input:checked").removeAttr("checked");`

http://davidsonsousa.net/en/post/how-to-clear-checkboxes-and-radio-buttons-using-jquery